# Rails 4 - Bootstrap 3 - Font Awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I can't seem to find a single gem or combination of gems that support Bootstrap 3 and Font Awesome in a Rails 4 project. What is the best way to get this working including Sass support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have these two bundled together to use them.

Font Awesome now has class names that don't clash with other frameworks (i.e. fa prefix).  Just use this gem: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

The Bootstrap SASS port should work just fine too: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: much less painful than recommended install on official documentation of Font-Awesome

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome is included in bootstrap. It just works. It is the secret ingredient in the bootstrap icon sauce

Answer (score 1):

Did you try font-awesome-rails and disabling bootstrap glyphicons?

Comment: how do you disable the bootstrap glyphicons in font-awesome-rails?

Comment: Use the below gem it has a different class name from the default bootstrap classes which will resolve your issues and negate the need to remove bootstrap glyphs

https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails